# C++ compile time iteration with get function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I would like to know if it is possible to do next thing.
For example, I have following template class with `constexpr` constructor, getter and `operator+()`.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, std::size_t NumEl>
class MyContainer {
public:
    // constructor 
    template <typename... Args>
    MyContainer(Args... tail): values{T(tail)...} {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == NumEl, "wrong number of arguments");
    }

    template<uint8_t Index>
    constexpr T& get() {
        return values[Index];
    }

    constexpr auto operator +(const MyContainer<T, NumEl>& other) {
        // no idea here

        return MyContainer<T, NumEl>() ;
    }
private:
    T values[NumEl];
};

int main() {
    MyContainer<double, 3> a(0.0, 1.0, 3.0);
    MyContainer<double, 3> b(1., 2.0, 5.0);

    assert(a.get<0>() == 0.0);
    assert(a.get<1>() == 1.0);

    auto c = a + b;

    assert(c.get<0>() == 1.0);
    assert(c.get<1>() == 3.0);
    assert(c.get<2>() == 8.0);
    return 0;    
}
```

I want to realize `operator+()` using `get()` function and variatic constructor and I stuck here. If I will create an array with sum, I know how to make a tuple for variadic constructor. But I can't simply write

```
T sumVals[NumEl] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < NumEl; ++i) {
    sumVals = values[i] + other.get<i>();
```

Because of `get<i>()` produce compile error. I assume that I should use recursive template, but have no idea how to realize that.

So, the question is how to realize `operator+()` in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Why that template `get` and not a `constexpr T& operator[]`, like [this](https://ideone.com/yomOIe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... there are some issues in your code.

First of all, if you want a `constexpr` class and a `constexpr` `get()` method is (I suppose) to initialize `constexpr` variables and check values compile time

So

1) define `constexpr` your constructor

```
   template <typename ... Args>
   constexpr MyContainer (Args ... tail): values{T(tail)...}
    { static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == NumEl, "wrong # of args"); }
```

or you can't make `constexpr` object of type `MyContainer`

2) define `constexpr` the `get()` method, or you can't check compile time the values of a `constexpr` `MyContainer`

3) you have also to define `get()` as `const` and returning a `T const &` value

```
  template <std::uint8_t Index>
  constexpr T const & get() const
   { return values[Index]; }
```

or you can't use `get()` with `const` object (and `constexpr` objects are also `const`)

Now, in `main()` you can define `a` and `b` as `constexpr` objects

```
constexpr MyContainer<double, 3> a(0.0, 1.0, 3.0);
constexpr MyContainer<double, 3> b(1., 2.0, 5.0);
```

and verify the vales, compile time, with `static_assert()`

```
static_assert(a.get<0>() == 0.0, "!");
static_assert(a.get<1>() == 1.0, "!");
```

Now the sum.

Usually the `operator+()` is defined as a function (a `friend` function, when needed), not as a method of the class.

I suggest to create a tag dispatched `private` `constexpr` constructor as follows

```
  template <std::size_t ... Is>
  constexpr MyContainer (MyContainer const & mc1,
                         MyContainer const & mc2, 
                         tagAdd const &,
                         std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
     : values{ mc1.values[Is] + mc2.values[Is] ... }
   { }
```

where `tagAdd` is an internal struct

```
  struct tagAdd { };
```

that permit to distinguish this contructor from similar constructor (maybe a constructor for `a - b`, one for `a * b`, etc.).

Your `friend` `operator+()` (defined inside the class) simply become

```
  friend constexpr MyContainer operator+ (MyContainer const & mc1,
                                          MyContainer const & mc2)
   { return {mc1, mc2, tagAdd{}, std::make_index_sequence<NumEl>{}}; }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t NumEl>
class MyContainer
 {
   private:
      struct tagAdd { };

      T values[NumEl];

      template <std::size_t ... Is>
      constexpr MyContainer (MyContainer const & mc1,
                             MyContainer const & mc2, 
                             tagAdd const &,
                             std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
         : values{ mc1.values[Is] + mc2.values[Is] ... }
       { }

   public:
      template <typename ... Args>
      constexpr MyContainer (Args ... tail): values{T(tail)...}
       { static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == NumEl, "wrong # of args"); }

      template <std::uint8_t Index>
      constexpr T const & get() const
       { return values[Index]; }

      friend constexpr MyContainer operator+ (MyContainer const & mc1,
                                              MyContainer const & mc2)
       { return {mc1, mc2, tagAdd{}, std::make_index_sequence<NumEl>{}}; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   constexpr MyContainer<double, 3> a(0.0, 1.0, 3.0);
   constexpr MyContainer<double, 3> b(1., 2.0, 5.0);

   static_assert(a.get<0>() == 0.0, "!");
   static_assert(a.get<1>() == 1.0, "!");

   constexpr auto c = a + b;

   static_assert(c.get<0>() == 1.0, "!");
   static_assert(c.get<1>() == 3.0, "!");
   static_assert(c.get<2>() == 8.0, "!");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! Consturctor constexpr I'd lost when I was making this example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `values[]` instead of `get<>()` in your `operator+()`. And to declare a temporary object to hold the sum, just make a copy of `*this`:

```
constexpr auto operator +(const MyContainer<T, NumEl>& other) {
    auto sumVals = *this;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NumEl; ++i) {
        sumVals.values[i] += other.values[i];
    return sumVals;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it. But if I want to store values in private section?

Comment: What do you mean? The `values[]` array is already in the private section.

Comment: So direct accessing to other.values[i] will produce a compile error

Comment: @ПавелРоманюк It won't, even if values is private within `MyContainer<T, NumEl>`. `MyContainer<T, NumEl>::operator+` is a member of `MyContainer<T, NumEl>` so it is allowed to access any member of any instance of `MyContainer<T, NumEl>`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Thank you. In my working code operator+ (not this example) is a template  like  'template <class T, size_t Size> operator+(const MyContainer<T, NumEl>& other)' and if we create, for instance,  MyContainer<double,3> and MyContainer<float, 3> i have this  ‘float MyContainer<float, 3ul>::values [3]’ is private